# Understanding why three nested functions are used in .attrTween

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nested

[This](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868) example from Mike Bostock has been very useful for me. It shows a point flowing endlessy along a curvilinear closed path. The code is very simple, except for the last lines which I don't understand. I write below the relevant code:

```
transition();

function transition() {
  circle.transition()
      .duration(10000)
      .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
      .each("end", transition);
}

// Returns an attrTween for translating along the specified path element.
function translateAlong(path) {
  var l = path.getTotalLength();
  return function(d, i, a) {
    return function(t) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
    };
  };
}
```

Why there are three nested functions? I know that the outer function `translateAlong` should return a function of `t` (time), but I don't understand the role of the intermediate `function(d, i, a)`. I've only tested that it cannot be omitted, but its arguments can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 3 functions. Let's name their levels:

```
function translateAlong(path) {//1st level here
  var l = path.getTotalLength();
  return function(d, i, a) {//2nd level here
    return function(t) {//3rd and last level
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
    };
  };
}
```

For answering your question, it's very important to understand that this...

```
.attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
```

... will call `translateAlong` **immediately** and get its return value. Which is this:

```
function(d, i, a) {//2nd level here
    return function(t) {//3rd and last level
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
    };
};
```

Now, let's go to the D3 v3 [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#attrTween) (the version in your link). It says:

> *transition.attrTween(name, tween)*
>
> Transitions the value of the attribute with the specified name according to the specified tween function. The starting and ending value of the transition are determined by tween; the tween function is invoked when the transition starts on each element, **being passed the current datum d, the current index i and the current attribute value a**, with the this context as the current DOM element. (emphasis mine)

As you can see by the parameters' names in the section I put in bold (even if Bostock never uses them, which explains your correct observation that *"its arguments can [be omitted]"*), the tween function is exactly the function you're asking about:

```
return function(d, i, a) {//this is the tween
    return function(t) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
    };
};
```

It's worth mentioning that, given how JavaScript closure works, the variable `l` (`var l = path.getTotalLength();`) is accessible to the tween function.